# Do MVC controllers need parameterized constructors for mocking?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, mocking, tdd

If I have a `controller` that does this:

```
//MyController

public ActionResult MyMethod(string someString)
{
  object test = new object();
  (new MyClassA()).DoSomething(test);
  return View();
}
```

Do I need to create a `constructor` for this controller so I can pass it a mocked version of `MyClassA`?

```
//Test

Mock<IMyClassA> a = new Mock<IMyClassA>();
a.Setup(m => m.DoSomething(new object());
MyController controller = new MyController(a.Object);
```

Comment: Yes, unless you have a default constructor for your controller.

Comment: So I'll need to create an additional constructor just for testing?  Is that bad practice?

Comment: Some would say you should be doing it the 2nd way (IoC with Dependency Injection using the constructor) regardless of whether you write controller tests or not, but definitely if you are.

Comment: Looks like you are using Moq for mocking. You could look into using a different mocking library such as FakeItEasy (https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) which has support for easily sending in mock params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, therefore it is usually a good practice to pass the references to all your services (classes) that you would like to use within a certain controller via its constructor and assign it to private fields of this controller. Then, when calling a certain Action you do not have to instantiate a certain class inside the body of this Action. It is also enabling you to test/mock it much easier.

Going even further you could think about using Inversion of Control (Dependency Injection) pattern and pass the interfaces of these classes in a constructor of a controller instead of passing the actual implementations.

So your controller could look like this:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public SomeController(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService; 
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_someService.GetSomeModel());
    }
}
```